# org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 19.083

Tags: java, database, selenium, intellij-idea, webdriver

##Getting TimeoutException

I have used the latest driver of chrome but I am getting error TimeoutException at the time of browser launch.
I am using SSH connection to jumpbox for DB connection and after connection when the browser should get to launch it throws an exception.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue since Chrome 85. Solved with increasing `PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT` to `60`.

Or this way:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If the exception persists just increase the timeout even more.